# Closing balance in mongo using aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a 2 collection

1.transactions:

> id:Account1,
> type of transaction:[credit or debit],
> amount:some currency
> date:Date

2. accounts:

> name:Account 1 or so on
> openingBalance:some amount

another collection of accounts has opening balance

```
    /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f214de9d150a21db8095395"),
    "name" : "Account 2",
    "openingBalance" : 10000.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f214de9d150a21db8095396"),
    "name" : "Account 1",
    "openingBalance" : 50000.0
}
```

and another collection has all the transaction by amount and by nature of transaction

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f214cf7608157bae3aeb41a"),
    "Account" : "Account 1",
    "NatureOfTranscation" : "credit",
    "Amount" : 140,
    "Date" : ISODate("2020-01-04T13:18:43.000Z")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f214d01608157bae3aeb41d"),
    "Account" : "Account 1",
    "NatureOfTranscation" : "debit",
    "Amount" : 140,
    "Date" : ISODate("2019-12-03T22:30:25.000Z")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f214d0b608157bae3aeb422"),
    "Account" : "Account 2",
    "NatureOfTranscation" : "credit",
    "Amount" : 140,
    "Date" : ISODate("2020-03-24T09:15:12.000Z")
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f214d14608157bae3aeb425"),
    "Account" : "Account 2",
    "NatureOfTranscation" : "credit",
    "Amount" : 140,
    "Date" : ISODate("2020-03-13T09:37:13.000Z")
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f214d1d608157bae3aeb42a"),
    "Account" : "Account 1",
    "NatureOfTranscation" : "debit",
    "Amount" : 140,
    "Date" : ISODate("2020-04-26T02:18:39.000Z")
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f214d28608157bae3aeb431"),
    "Account" : "Account 2",
    "NatureOfTranscation" : "credit",
    "Amount" : 140,
    "Date" : ISODate("2020-06-26T03:07:19.000Z")
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f214d33608157bae3aeb436"),
    "Account" : "Account 2",
    "NatureOfTranscation" : "credit",
    "Amount" : 140,
    "Date" : ISODate("2020-06-22T12:18:13.000Z")
}
```

Now using aggregation

1. Sort by Date
2. Group by Account
3. if it is credit openingbalance + amount will be closing balance for that document and vice versa

> I have tried this

```
db.getCollection('col').aggregate([
    {
        $sort: { 'Date': 1}
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$Account',
            transactions: {
                $push: '$$ROOT'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            id: 1,
            transactions:1, 
            count: 1
            }
     }
 ])
```

> So Far i have got this.

```
    /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "Account 1",
    "transactions" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f214d01608157bae3aeb41d"),
            "Account" : "Account 1",
            "NatureOfTranscation" : "debit",
            "Amount" : 140,
            "Date" : ISODate("2019-12-03T22:30:25.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f214cf7608157bae3aeb41a"),
            "Account" : "Account 1",
            "NatureOfTranscation" : "credit",
            "Amount" : 140,
            "Date" : ISODate("2020-01-04T13:18:43.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f214d1d608157bae3aeb42a"),
            "Account" : "Account 1",
            "NatureOfTranscation" : "debit",
            "Amount" : 140,
            "Date" : ISODate("2020-04-26T02:18:39.000Z")
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "Account 2",
    "transactions" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f214d14608157bae3aeb425"),
            "Account" : "Account 2",
            "NatureOfTranscation" : "credit",
            "Amount" : 140,
            "Date" : ISODate("2020-03-13T09:37:13.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f214d0b608157bae3aeb422"),
            "Account" : "Account 2",
            "NatureOfTranscation" : "credit",
            "Amount" : 140,
            "Date" : ISODate("2020-03-24T09:15:12.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f214d33608157bae3aeb436"),
            "Account" : "Account 2",
            "NatureOfTranscation" : "credit",
            "Amount" : 140,
            "Date" : ISODate("2020-06-22T12:18:13.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f214d28608157bae3aeb431"),
            "Account" : "Account 2",
            "NatureOfTranscation" : "credit",
            "Amount" : 140,
            "Date" : ISODate("2020-06-26T03:07:19.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

> Desired result:

```
    {
    "_id" : "Account 1",
    "transactions" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f214d01608157bae3aeb41d"),
            "Account" : "Account 1",
            "NatureOfTranscation" : "debit",
            "Amount" : 140,
            "Date" : ISODate("2019-12-03T22:30:25.000Z"),
            "closingBalance":49860
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f214cf7608157bae3aeb41a"),
            "Account" : "Account 1",
            "NatureOfTranscation" : "credit",
            "Amount" : 140,
            "Date" : ISODate("2020-01-04T13:18:43.000Z"),
            "closingBalance":50000
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f214d1d608157bae3aeb42a"),
            "Account" : "Account 1",
            "NatureOfTranscation" : "debit",
            "Amount" : 140,
            "Date" : ISODate("2020-04-26T02:18:39.000Z"),
            "closingBalance":49500

        }
    ]
}
```

Any suggestion of regarding the database model also will be welcome.
Thanks In advance.

Comment: _"So Far i have got this..."_ You can use this result's `transactions` array as input to a reduction operation which returns the same array with additional `closingBalance` field for each of the array elements (calculated by accumulating for each element, based upon the `NatureOfTranscation` and `Amount`. See [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) aggregation array operator.

Comment: @prasad_ Thanks for help, the `transactions` is **array of object** reduce doesn't allow operation on that.

Comment: Hint: You have to imagine the reduction in terms of a for-loop (then you can construct it).

Comment: hi @prasad_ can you least give me flowchart of the stages needed to be use in pipeline. it will be great help.

Comment: Can you tell me about the `NatureOfTranscation` values "ccredit" and "debit", and how they were applied to get the desired result.

Comment: @prasad_ Thanks for reply, so i was thinking looping through "Account 1" depending upon `NatureOfTranscation` i will either inc the closing balance or reducing it. it is like bank statement. "Account 1" will be having opening balance each transaction in collection either we added in opening balance or reduced and we will call it as `closingBalance`

Comment: The number of debits and credits are not same in the input, so-far and the desired result. Please correct or explain. (In the desired result, there are three documents with credits and one document with debit. But, in the input documents, there are two of each).

Comment: @prasad_ Sir i have updated question again. can you please take a look and guide me.